# Changing font on chart with plotly

Tags: r, plotly

I am plotting some plot with plotly. So everything is ok but I am not satisfied with font appearance. Namely in legend I have one font while for x and y-axis I have other. So can anybody help how to fix this problem and have same font like font in legend ?

```
 x1 = lcBR$p
    y1 = lcBR$L
    
    x2 = lcAR$p
    y2 = lcAR$L
   
    
    fig <- plot_ly(x = ~ x1, y = ~ x1, name = '45º', type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines',
                   line = list(color = "black", width = 2)) 
    
    fig <- fig %>% add_trace(x = ~ x1,  y = ~ y1, name = 'Before reform', mode = 'lines',
                             line = list(color = "red", width = 2, dash = "solid"))
    fig <- fig %>% add_trace(x ~ x2, y = ~ y2, name = 'After reform', mode = 'lines',
                             line = list(color = "blue", width = 2, dash = "dash"))
           
    f <- list(
      family = "Courier New, monospace",
      size = 18,
      color = "#7f7f7f")
    
    x <- list(
      title = "Share of Population",
      titlefont = f)
    
    y <- list(
      title = "Share of income",
      titlefont = f)
  
    fig <- fig %>% layout(xaxis = x, yaxis = y)
    
    fig
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks a bit different than what "normal" python code in plotly looks like; is this R-code? However, you can use `fig.update_layout` to update the layout throughout your figure and `fig.update_xaxes` to change the appearance of the x-axis including text; have a look at https://plotly.com/python/figure-labels/#global-and-local-font-specification

Comment: The above can be used with Python, but I am not sure whether it also works with R, see https://plotly.com/r/font/